# Replace fragment using FragmentTransaction calls fragment create multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Here is my code

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment contentFragment, Fragment lastFragment, int resourseID,int animationType, boolean addToStack) {
if (contentFragment != lastFragment) {

   mContentFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   FragmentTransactionExtended fragmentTransactionExtended = new FragmentTransactionExtended(this, mContentFragmentTransaction,lastFragment,contentFragment, resourseID);
   fragmentTransactionExtended.addTransition(animationType);
   mContentFragmentTransaction.replace(resourseID, contentFragment);
   if (addToStack) {
       mContentFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
   }
   mContentFragmentTransaction.commit();
   }

}
```

The problem is, everytime I changeFragment using this method, the fragment's oncreate will fire multiple times, first time, it runs once, second time twice , third time three times, hope someone know what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

`addToBackstack` creates a snapshot of your fragments state. Which means when you press the back button, you are actually reverting to the last state that `addToBackstack` was called on.

You have to call replace on the *container* that has the fragment, not the fragment itself.  So instead of calling `replace(R.id.dashboard, fragment)` it should be `replace(R.id.dashboards_container, fragment)`.

have you tried to use an other method, like remove(), then do an add(). or anything similar? some people say's replace() method does not always behave correctly.
If the state of the activity has already been saved its no longer safe to call commit. You must call `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead.
Even if you use replace or remove calls you can't do this.  Only work around I have found is to create a new instance of a fragment and add it every time. Once you remove or replace a fragment it is best to drop all of your references to it so the GC can take care of it.

regards `maven`